# Lucene indexing best praktice

Tags: mongodb, indexing, lucene

Started learning Lucene, I am trying create auto suggest based on input. 
In database (mongoDb) there are 6 fields, autosuggest is searched by 3 of them, but for user should be returned all 6 fields.
So want to ask, what is better:

1. Store all 6 fields but index only 3 of them in `Lucene`?
2. Store only `id` index 3 of them, and then request all data from database by id?

Interested in fast performance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to auto suggest 3 fields, you must analyze 3 fields on Lucene index. Others 3 fields you can retrieve from MongoDB by id.